# Control relés según temperatura, Arduino NODEMCU

Tags: arduino

Saludos y gracias por vuestro tiempo. Estoy estancado con un problema y no sé como solucionarlo, estoy con un proyecto de control de zonas para la calefacción central. En el código de abajo quiero que 2 sensores DHT22 me hagan lecturas, y al seleccionar una temperatura, que se me activen los relés de los radiadores y el de la caldera, ejemplo:

- Despacho, lo quiero a 23 grados, al estar a 21 se activa el relé del radiador y el relé de la caldera.
- Salón, lo quiero a 22 grados, al estar a 22.5 el relé del radiador no se activa y el relé de la caldera se desactiva.

¿Cómo hago para que el relé de la caldera, mientres haya un radiador en marcha no se desactive?

```html
void loop() {

  if (millis() > anteriorRefreshDatos + 2000){
    anteriorRefreshDatos = millis();
    float tempDespacho = dhtDespacho.readTemperature();
    float tempSalon = dhtSalon.readTemperature();
      if (isnan(tempDespacho) || isnan(tempSalon)){
      Serial.println("Fallo en lectura de temperatura");
      return;}
        if (calderaHabilitada = 1){
          if (tempDespacho + histeresis >= tempDeseadaDespacho && tempDespacho > 0 ) {
            digitalWrite(releDespacho, LOW);
            digitalWrite(releSalon, LOW);
            digitalWrite(releCaldera, LOW);
            }
            if (tempSalon + histeresis >= tempDeseadaSalon && tempSalon > 0 ) {
            digitalWrite(releDespacho, LOW);
            digitalWrite(releSalon, LOW);
            digitalWrite(releCaldera, LOW);
            }
        else if (tempDespacho < tempDeseadaDespacho && tempDespacho > 0 )
        {
        digitalWrite(releDespacho, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(releSalon, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(releCaldera, HIGH);}
        else if (tempSalon < tempDeseadaSalon && tempSalon > 0 )
        {
        digitalWrite(releDespacho, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(releSalon, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(releCaldera, HIGH);}
      else
      {
        digitalWrite(releDespacho, LOW);
        digitalWrite(releSalon, LOW);
        digitalWrite(releCaldera, LOW);
      }

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pon una condición de que la caldera se encienda cuando cualquiera de los dos radiadores esté encendido.
Antes de apagar la caldera, verificar si algún radiador esta activado, entonces no apagar la caldera.